# Что означает строка  RaisePropertyChanged(() => MyDateTime);

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm

Скачал шаблон в MS VS 2010 для MVVM через саму студию, создал новый проект и увидел там такую строку. Что она может означать?

Comment: Точнее что означает в целом ясно, но синтаксис удивляет

Answer (score 5):

RaisePropertyChanges — по смыслу, функция, которая запускает событие PropertyChanged для данного свойства. Раз строчка выглядит таким образом, значит функция такая продвинутая, что вместо строки с названием свойства может принимать, так сказать, лямбду с самим этим свойством, а MyDateTime, видимо, — собственно свойство.

PS: Если интересно, можно почитать о том, [как такой черной магии можно добиться](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671968/retrieving-property-name-from-lambda-expression) (и как, вероятно, они добились).

Answer (score 5):

К правильному ответу [[@dog_funtom](/users/2351/dog_funtom)](/users/2351/dog_funtom) кроме +1 добавлю, что в .NET 4.5 есть более простой путь с более белой магией:

```
private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string caller = null)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
}

int property;
public int Property
{
    get { return property; }
    set
    {
        if (property != value)
            return;
        property = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(); // здесь включается магия [CallerMemberName]
    }
}
```