# Binding text у textblock'a не работает

Tags: c#, xaml, binding

Использую фреймворк catel, обновляю значение в таймере при этом посылаю событие того что контент обновлен, но изменений не происходит.
В чем проблема?

XAML:

```
<TextBlock Margin="2,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding NowPlayingTime}" />
```

C#:

```
void _dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AboveTime = string.Format("{0:hh:mm:ss}",
        TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(_controlPlayer.NaturalDurationTimeSpan));
    NowPlayingTime = string.Format("{0:hh:mm:ss}",
        TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(_controlPlayer.NowPlayingPosition));
}
public string NowPlayingTime
{
    get { return _nowPlayingTime; }
    private set
    {
        _nowPlayingTime = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => NowPlayingTime);
    }
}
```

Оба метода не обновляют значения, ни `AboveTime`, ни `NowPlayingTime`.

Comment: Почему бы вам не воспользоваться [белой магией](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/204894/182346)?

Comment: Белая магия здесь абсолютно ни к чему, обновление списка у меня прекрасно работает, но вот **текст блок** никак не хочет обновлять данные.

Comment: А может, у вас не так установлен `DataContext`? Например, может быть, свойство `NowPlayingTime` у вас в окне или юзерконтроле, а в `DataContext`'е объект VM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел решение проблемы, не верно был указан формат строки, вот так все успешно работает.

```
private void _dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AboveTime = string.Format("{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", _controlPlayer.NaturalDurationTimeSpan);
    NowPlayingTime = string.Format("{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", _controlPlayer.NowPlayingPositionTimeSpan);
}
```